# Should a void* pointer passed in by a callback be deleted

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory-management

When a third party API defines a function pointer as a callback that takes a void* like so:

```
typedef void (__stdcall *CALLBACK)(int type,void * data);
```

And the callback implementation is then passed into the api via a function call like so:

```
int __stdcall SetCallbackToGetAsyncStuff(CALLBACK func);
```

And API would then invoke the implementation of `CALLBACK` when things happen.

Is it the responsibility of the implementation method to clean up the `void*` pointer.
Or is it a general assumption that the pointer would be cleaned up by the invoking code?
Would be wise to copy the content of the `void*`, provided you know the size via the type `enum,` into your own stack variable? 
What should one assume if there is no documentation aside from the above information in the header file.

Comment: Defensively, you should assume that `void * data` isn't going to stick around forever and that that memory at a minimum may be reused for something else.

Comment: This issue of "who owns it" is why C++ is trying to move away from passing pointers and using move sematics to efficiently pass by value.

Comment: Note that if you try to use `operator delete` on the pointer in C++, *it will not call the destructor if the object is a class with a destructor*.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. C uses type enums and `void*` pointers with malloc/free. C++ uses inheritance and new/delete. Figuring out what language you're using will help in asking more coherent questions.

Comment: The above, plus check if the lib provides any other function that allows you to return the void* when you are done with the data it points to. The documentation for the lib is very poor if it does not explicitly define the ownership/lifetime of the data returned by the callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper answer on the question "who needs to delete the pointer", is "the same side who allocated it". If a library is not compiled with your code and resides in a .dll-file, it use in general case a different CRT. You cannot create object with one CRT and delete it with another.

A 3rd party library may rely on memory buffers allocated by your app, or it can allocate memory by itself and provide your app with access to it. If you didn't allocate any memory, associated with the data passed to a callback, you shouldn't delete it. At least when using well-designed library.

It is hard to tell from your question, who allocated the memory.

Comment: What if the dll is getting loaded into my program with a LoadLibrary call. Still different CRT?

Comment: Yes, of course. Doesn't matter how it is loaded. Only matters how it is built. Note that _in fact_ it can use the same CRT, but _in general_ it won't.

Comment: As noted in a comment above, deleting a void* pointer doesn't even call the destructor. Aside from DLL issues, deleting something you didn't new is fundamentally bad design.

Answer (score 2):

It is up to the client code how they define callback. If callback function assumes the ownership, then it should free.

Please take note of the other situations that same data pointer can be passed to multiple callbacks and cause undefined behaviour of the program.

Or you can keep the ownership with its creator.

Comment: It is on the creator of the object who assumes that ownership lies to client.